# href link button not working html

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code below for the menu, all links scroll down to a certain section, except for the Blog button that should send the user to another link, but it doesn't work, it only works if I write click and choose open in new tab

here is the code

```
<div class="header-menu-and-meta">
    <ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="4" href="#cta-title-1">contact</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="3" href="#clients-testmonials">clients</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="1" href="#fun-facts">about</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="0" href="#header">main</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="header-meta">
        <div class="hm-content">
            <a class="header-btn scroll-to btn small colorful hover-white" href="http://example.com/blog/">Blog</a>
        </div><!-- .hm-content end -->
    </div><!-- .header-meta end -->                             
    <div class="mobile-menu-btn hamburger hamburger--slider">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </div><!-- .mobile-menu-btn -->
<!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->
</div><!-- .header-menu-and-meta end -->
```

Comment: you want the link to open in new tab or just redirect to link

Comment: @sanojlawrence I want it to redirct, but I think the JS is causing it not to work

Comment: where is the `JS` you have not mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open your link in a new tab you can use the `target='_blank'` attribute. If you wish to open it in the same window then don't include this attribute. See the code snippet below. (Note that the target blank attribute will not work on this site, so test it locally or on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qr6gzfw0/))

Also, ensure the you have the full url, including `www.`

```html
<div class="header-menu-and-meta">
  <ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">


    <li><a data-scroll-nav="4" href="#cta-title-1">contact</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll-nav="3" href="#clients-testmonials">clients</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll-nav="1" href="#fun-facts">about</a></li>
    <li><a data-scroll-nav="0" href="#header">main</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="header-meta">
    <div class="hm-content">
      <a class="header-btn scroll-to btn small colorful hover-white" href="http://www.example.com/blog/" target="_blank">Blog</a>
    </div>
    <!-- .hm-content end -->
  </div>
  <!-- .header-meta end -->
  <div class="mobile-menu-btn hamburger hamburger--slider">
    <span class="hamburger-box">
      <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <!-- .mobile-menu-btn -->
  <!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->
</div>
<!-- .header-menu-and-meta end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine for me it redirects to link.

```html
<div class="header-menu-and-meta">
    <ul id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="4" href="#cta-title-1">contact</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="3" href="#clients-testmonials">clients</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="1" href="#fun-facts">about</a></li>
        <li><a data-scroll-nav="0" href="#header">main</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="header-meta">
        <div class="hm-content">
            <a class="header-btn scroll-to btn small colorful hover-white" href="http://example.com/blog/">Blog</a>
        </div><!-- .hm-content end -->
    </div><!-- .header-meta end -->                             
    <div class="mobile-menu-btn hamburger hamburger--slider">
        <span class="hamburger-box">
            <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
        </span>
    </div><!-- .mobile-menu-btn -->
    <!-- <div class="clearfix"></div> -->
</div><!-- .header-menu-and-meta end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the behaviour of redirection of the anchor tags by setting the target attribute.

by default property it has is self: `target="_self"`

You want to achieve is `target="_blank"`

[image]

I took the image clip from Mozilla Developers Network.

Comment: I think the problem is JS related, I tried everything but still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem it was in the JS files, the HTMLAnchorElement was set to preventdefault

Comment: you cant answer your own question.

Comment: I can if I found the solution and thought about helping others who face the same thing